# Issue on implementing jdbc dao support in spring application

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, dao

I was trying to access database using jdbcdao as per the following example:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-jdbcdaosupport-examples/

userdao, userdaoimpl,daocontext and datacontext.xml are as follows:

DAOIMPL

```
public class UserDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements UserDAO {    

    /*Creates User */
    public void insertUser(User user){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Users " +
            "(id, username, password,role) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";

        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, new Object[] { user.getUserId(),
                user.getUserName(),user.getPassWord() 
        });

    }
}
```

DAO

```
import java.util.List;

import spring.web.models.User;

public interface UserDAO {
    public void insertUser(User user);

}
```

DAOCONTEXT.XML

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="userDAO" class="spring.web.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="primaryDataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

DATA-CONTEXT.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

    <bean  id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" name="driverClassName" />
        <property value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.72.68:1521:d2he"
            name="url" />
        <property value="aaryal_1" name="username" />
        <property value="oracle" name="password" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The error I am facing is as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]:
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'primaryDataSource' of bean class [spring.web.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl]: 
Bean property 'primaryDataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
 Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Please suggest me what did I miss.

Comment: [`JdbcDaoSupport` has not property `primaryDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html). Change it to `dataSource`, which _is_ a settable property of `JdbcDaoSupport`. You can't just make up properties. Even the example you linked use `dataSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `setPrimaryDataSource` method in UserDAOImpl class. The error says it all. It's expecting a property called `primaryDataSource` in your class, but can't find it. Hence the error.

You'll need to do this:

```
private DataSource dataSource;

public void setPrimaryDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

EDIT:

If you go through the API of [JdbcDaoSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html), the `setDataSource` method already exists. So to solve your error, you can either do the above, or simply rename your `DataSource` bean name to `dataSource`